# libcurl inserts additional data to download files

Tags: c, libcurl, fwrite, fflush

I use libcurl in my C code to download files given their urls. My code looks similar to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
    return written;
}

int progress_func(void *ptr, double TotalToDownload, double NowDownloaded,
            double TotalToUpload, double NowUploaded)
{
    struct my_custom_struct *my_dummy_data = (struct my_custom_struct *) data;
    //do some stuffs here
    return 0;
}

void *download_with_curl(void *data)
{
    char *url = (char *) data;

    int res = 0;

    // My custom struct to store data
    struct my_custom_struct my_dummy_data;

    char errbuff[CURL_ERROR_SIZE] = {0};
    CURL *curl_handle;

    /* init the curl session */
    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

    /* set URL to get here */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url);

    /* disable progress meter, set to 0L to enable*/
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0L);

    /* send all data to this function*/
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, RESPOND_TIME);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 30L);

    /* set the progress function */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progress_func);

    /* set the progress data */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, &my_dummy_data);

     /* provide a buffer to store errors in */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuff);


    FILE *pagefile = fopen(path_to_where_I_want_to_store_the_file, "wb");
    /* write the page body to this file handle */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, pagefile);
    /* get the file*/
    int status = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
    res = 0;

    int response_code;
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl_handle, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);

    fclose(pagefile);

    if (status != 0) {
        log_warn("CURL ERROR %d: %s", status, errbuff);
        response_code = -status;
    }
    /* cleanup curl stuff */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    // sockfd = create a sockfd
    // bind, listen
    do {
        // accept new connection

        char *url;
        // receive the url from client
        pthread_t tid;
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, download_with_curl, url);
    } while (1);
}
```

When I send a single download request, the code works fine. "Works fine" means that the md5sum values of the original file and the downloaded file are equal. However, when I send multiple requests to download multiple files, only the first file that is downloaded has the correct md5sum value. To be clear, if I send requests to download files A (200MB), B (5MB) and C (50MB) in that order, only file B is correctly downloaded because it is finished first. Files A and C will have incorrect md5sum values. Moreover, when I check the content of files A and C, it looks like curl just inserts random segments of data into them. If the original file content is

> This is the content of a file

then the downloaded file is like

> This is the #$%!@#%@% content of $%(#(!)$()$%||@#$%*&) a file

After spending two days of debugging, I finally solved the problem (I hope so). All I did was just flushing the data after calling fwrite. The function `write_data` now looks like this:

```
static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
    fflush((FILE *) stream);
    return written;
}
```

I do not know if it completely solves the problem or not. Could anyone explain why it behaves that way and give my a solution to this?

**UPDATE 1**

It seems that there is something to do with `fwrite()`'s internal buffer. Changing from `fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream)` to `write(fileno(stream), ptr, size * nmemb)` seems to give the same result as using `fflush()`.

**UPDATE 2**

Using the default write function (remove the option `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`) of libcurl gives the same problem.

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html documentation is not very clear for me ... but the given example does not show that the callback function must call `fwrite`. What happends if you just do nothing in `write_data` ? Could be that your code write twice the file ???

Comment: @pifor In write data we suppose to do something with the data stored in _ptr_ (e.g., write to a file). If I do not do anything, the file won't be written. The example stores the data into memory instead of writing to a file so it does not call _fwrite_.